# appending the whole content of file to the other one after a phrase

Tags: shell

```
`echo "Enter input file name:"
 read input_file
 echo "Enter phrase to search for:"
 read phrase
 echo "Enter number of lines to extact:"
 read num_lines
 echo "Enter output file name:"
 read output file
 grep -A $num_lines "$phrase" $input_file>temp.txt
 cat temp.txt >>$output_file
 FILE_TO_INSERT="temp.txt"
 FILE_TO_MODIFY="file2.txt"
 LINE_NUMBER=$(grep -n "ATOMIC" "$FILE_TO_MODIFY" | cut -d ":" -f 1)
 echo $LINE_NUMBER
 sed -i "${LINE_NUMBER}r FILE_TO_INSERT" ${FILE_TO_MODIFY}`
```

## The sed command do nothing.

## Any comment?

~

How can I append the whole content of a file1.txt to file2.txt after a phrase?

Comment: Put a `$` in front of `FILE_TO_INSERT`?

Answer (score 1):

Why jump through all those hoops to begin with. If I understand what you are needing, inserting `temp.txt` in `file2.txt` after the line containing `"ATOMIC:..."`, then a simple call to `sed` locating `"ATOMIC:"` at the beginning of a line (with or without optional leading whitespace) is all that is needed, e.g.

```bash
sed '/^[[:space:]]*ATOMIC:/r temp.txt' file2.txt
```

Unless there is some magic unexplained about obtaining a line-number to you, then it's not needed and you can do it all in a single call to `sed`.

**Example Use/Output**

Example `file2.txt`,

```
$ cat file2.txt
Some stuff in the file
that ultimately contains
the line with
ATOMIC:SOME:OTHER:STUFF
in the file
```

The `temp.txt` file to insert on the line after `"ATOMIC:..."`, e.g.

```
$ cat temp.txt
==
this is the new file to insert
==
```

And the result (add the `-i` option for in-place substitution in `file2.txt`)

```
$ sed '/^[[:space:]]*ATOMIC:/r temp.txt' file2.txt
Some stuff in the file
that ultimately contains
the line with
ATOMIC:SOME:OTHER:STUFF
==
this is the new file to insert
==
in the file
```

As noted in the comment below your question, if you need to provide `temp.txt` as a variable, then surround the `sed` expression in double-quotes so variable-expansion will occur and don't forget the `'$'` preceding the variable name., e.g.

```bash
foo=temp.txt; sed "/^[[:space:]]*ATOMIC:/r $foo" file2.txt
```

If I misinterpreted your question, let me know and edit your question and provide sample data. I'm happy to help further.